# Dynamically calculated prices save after add to cart

Tags: product, cart

We tried to update the product price after addto cart. I done the following code but cant get the item product price.

In app/etc/modules

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <test_Productoptions>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
       <depends>
            <Mage_Checkout />
       </depends>
    </test_Productoptions>
  </modules>
</config>
```

In app/code/local/test/productoptions/etc

0.0.1
        
    
    
        
            
                Test_Productoptions_Model

```
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <priceupdate_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>test_productoptions/observer</class>
                    <method>updatePrice</method>
                </priceupdate_observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

I Write the observer in app/code/local/test/productoptions/model

```
<?php
class Test_Productoptions_Model_Observer
{

    public function _construct()
      {
      }

    public function getNewPrice()
      {
        //Your new functionality here
        //
        $newprice = "";

        return $newprice;
      }

     public function updatePrice( Varien_Event_Observer $observer ) 
     {

        $quote_item  = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $product     = $quote_item->getProduct();
        $quantity    = $product->getQty();

       echo $quote_item->getPrice();
      die();

     }
}
```

In this $quote_item->getPrice() is return null value. How to get the currently added product price from quote.

Answer (score 2):

First set this code in `config.xml`

```
<checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    <observers>
        <custom_catalog_price_observer>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>productoptions/observer</class>
            <method>setProductCustomPrice</method>
        </custom_catalog_price_observer>
    </observers>
</checkout_cart_product_add_after>
```

You should use below method in Observer

```
public function setProductCustomPrice($observer)
{
    // Get the quote item
    $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    // Ensure we have the parent item, if it has one
    $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
    // Load the custom price

    $org_price = $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();

    //SET YOUR CUSTOM PRICE HERE
    $custom_price = $org_price + 15;

    $price = $custom_price;
    // Set the custom price
    $item->setCustomPrice($price);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
    // Enable super mode on the product.
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
}
```

Replace this line `$custom_price = $org_price + 15;` with your custom price logic

Comment: Hi, i cant add the product to cart. Show the error message as "Canot add to product in cart".

Comment: This is my function - `public function updatePrice( Varien_Event_Observer $observer ) 
     {     $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
          $org_price = $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();
        $custom_price = $org_price * $_REQUEST['cellcount'];
        // echo $quote_item->getPrice();
        //$new_price   = 2000*$_REQUEST['cellcount'];
        $item->setCustomPrice($custom_price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($custom_price);
        $item->save();
         
     }`

Comment: If not logged in customer, i got the message as  "Cannot add the item to shopping cart". Once login , its work perfectly.

Comment: I think you are missing `$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);` line. You need to use `$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);` in order to make `$item->setCustomPrice();` and `$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);` to work.

Comment: Hi, I added the `$item->setCustomPrice($custom_price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($custom_price);
         $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        $item->save();` But same error message show. This issue occured not logged customers only.

Comment: What's `$item->save();` here ? I never mentioned that. Can you use EXACT code/method that I have posted, for testing, to check if it's working for you ?

Comment: Hi , Just Remove the $item->save(). Its working fine. How to implement same as in admin order creation page?

Comment: Instead of placing your event observer code into the `<frontend>`, put it into `<global>` node in your module's config.xml file. This will work for `front` and `admin` also. BTW, you can accept this answer :)

Comment: Hi, i tried to above, but not work for custom price.

Comment: Hi, I tried the above code its work fine. But I first add to cart the product  after login, order item custom fields set to null. Where to update the custom field values after login?

Answer (score 0):

Use below mentioned event it's will work perfectly.

In your /app/code/local/{namespace}/{yourmodule}/etc/config.xml:

```
<events>
    <sales_quote_add_item>
        <observers>
            <priceupdate_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>productoptions/observer</class>
                <method>updatePrice</method>
            </priceupdate_observer>
        </observers>
    </sales_quote_add_item>
</events>
```

And then create an Observer class at /app/code/local/{namespace}/{yourmodule}/Model/Observer.php

```
class Test_Productoptions_Model_Observer
{
public function updatePrice($observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
    $new_price = 1254 // your price logic goes here
    $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
    $quote_item->save();
}
}
```

Here is the code to get subtotal and product price

```
$event = $observer->getQuote();
        $subTotal = $event->getSubtotal();
        $grandTotal = $event->getGrandTotal();

        foreach($event->getAllItems() as $quote_item) {
            echo $quote_item->getPrice();
        }
```

Comment: Hi, I need to some calculation based on currently added product. But i cant get the price from quote.  I will try same code above, its working. But need to get the price from quote. `$new_price = $quote_item->getPrice()*4`

Comment: I have updated the answer see use given codes in updatePrice() function and do whatever you want

Comment: I want get the price from quote, but $quote_item->getPrice() is return null value. How to get the price from quote?

Comment: $quote_item->getPrice() it should return price for more see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139697/magento-get-cart-single-item-price-incl-tax